# Why is the value that my controller recieves from Axios always null?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, axios, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this simple Axios call:

```
 var payload = "this is a test";
 const dt = { rockText: payload };
 const request = axios.put(`/api/rocks/${rockId}/rockText`, dt);
```

It connects to a controller like this:

```
    [HttpPut("{id}/rockText")]
    public IActionResult PutRockText(Int32 id, [FromBody] string rockText)
    { ... }
```

But `rockText` is **always** null in the controller even though I know it's not when being used by Axios.

I've tried so many variations of the Axios call, but it's always null.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Which side is the problem - does making the request from a different client work?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I only have one client right now

Comment: Postman, curl, `fetch` in your browser, ...? You need to do some basic debugging so you know whether you need to fix the sending or receiving of the request.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry I see what you mean.  I tried it through Postman and it was null as well on the api side.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but the `id` comes through ok though. :/

Comment: Because you're handling the path but not the body correctly - I'm not familiar with .NET but the answer below seems very plausible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass json data with axios,you need to set `Content-Type`,here is a demo:

axios(I use 1 to replace `${rockId}` to test):

```
var payload = "this is a test";
const request = axios.put(`/api/rocks/1/rockText`, JSON.stringify(payload),
               { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPut("{id}/rockText")]
public IActionResult PutRockText(int id,[FromBody]string rock)
{
     return Ok();
}
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the model binder cannot resolve the payload.  The reason is that it's expecting a string, but you're actually passing a json object with a property `rockText`.

I would create a class to represent the json you're sending:

```
public class Rock
{
    public string RockText { get; set; }
}


[HttpPut("{id}/rockText")]
public IActionResult PutRockText(Int32 id, [FromBody] Rock rock)
{ ... }
```

---

Alternatively, you could try passing the string from axios:

```
var payload = "this is a test";
const request = axios.put(`/api/rocks/${rockId}/rockText`, payload);
```

Comment: Thanks I changed it to your 2nd example, but it's still null... the rockId comes through ok though

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell did you try my first suggestion?  That's the one I'd recommend

Comment: I just did, but it is still null :(

Comment: I've tested and it works for me using postman, you'll need to provide more debugging details @SkyeBoniwell